# Use serial ID for multiple columns and return it from INSERT

Tags: postgresql, insert, sequence, ado.net

I am using `Npgsql` and I want to be able to do an `insert`, and `if` statement that will do an `update` and then return a value so when `ExecuteScalar` is called it reads that value.  This was done fine in MSSQL but I'm now trying to support PostgreSQL and I can't seem to get it right.

The SQL is similar to this:

```
insert into mytable (name, uniquecallid) 
values (@name, @uniquecallid); 

DO
$do$
BEGIN 
IF coalesce(@UniqueCallId,'') = '' THEN 
    SET @UniqueCallId = coalesce(@CallIdPad, '')
                     || cast(varchar(50), select currval('mytable_id_seq'));
    UPDATE mytable SET UniqueCallId = @UniqueCallId
    WHERE Id = select currval('mytable_id_seq');
END IF;
END
$do$

select currval('mytable_id_seq');
```

This errors with a "syntax error near select".

What can I do to get this to return the latest value inserted?

I believe this is a Npgsql issue as when inspecting the SQL that it executes the parameters are replaced with the values but the `DO` block doesn't have the values in place of parameters.

Comment: I think the issue maybe Npgsql doesn't like the DO anonymous code as when I look at it as it errors its converted all the parameters to values but not the anonymous code

Comment: I can't really as I'd need to say in the code is this postgres or mssql, if so call the function etc etc :(

Comment: Unrelated but: `WHERE Id = currval('mytable_id_seq')` is enough. No need for a select there.

Comment: This question has several solutions to the "insert or update" problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/330315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Syntax errors

Immediate causes for the error:

```
WHERE  id = select currval('mytable_id_seq');
```

And a missing semicolon at the end of the `DO` statement:

```
...
$do$;
```

#### Better query

On a closer look, this does ***not*** seem to be another case of `UPSERT`.
It would seem one of the inserted columns needs to depend on multiple input values in combination with the freshly retrieved value for a serial ID. Try this largely simplified statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, uniquecallid) 
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , CASE WHEN t.uniquecallid <> '' THEN t.uniquecallid
            ELSE COALESCE(t.callidpad, '') || t.id END 

FROM (
   SELECT nextval('mytable_id_seq') AS id
        , '@name'::text             AS name         -- provide values here, once
        , '@UniqueCallId'::text     AS uniquecallid
        , '@CallIdPad'::text        AS callidpad
   ) t
RETURNING id;
```

An explicit cast to `text` (or your actual undisclosed data type(s)) is needed.

This is equivalent to the presented code, just with legal syntax and **much faster** - unless there are triggers or non-standard default values you did not declare ...

#### Simpler with `currval()`

On an even closer look, this can be simplified further:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, uniquecallid) 
SELECT '@name'::text
     , COALESACE( NULLIF('@UniqueCallId'::text, '')
                , COALESCE('@CallIdPad'::text, '') || currval('mytable_id_seq'))
RETURNING id;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences/13394177#13394177)

Comment: @Jon: You may be interested in the addendum.