# Surrogate key resolution, or what am I missing in the Surrogate v Natural argument?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-theory, surrogate-key

I've read a lot from both camps in the surrogate vs. natural key debate. What I am struggling to understand, and what seems to be glossed over, especially in explaining how surrogate keys are more efficient, is how do referencing tables resolve a surrogate key?

Say, I am using an ORM in an application, and have a `userID` in an application object. now we want to insert into a `SelectedTask` table and a `SubTask` table that are defined as follows (ignore the awkwardness of the real word example):

```
CREATE TABLE SelectedTask(
userID INT References User(userID)
taskNumber INT,
name TEXT ,
jobSiteID INT References Site(jobSiteID),
PRIMARY KEY (???)
);

CREATE TABLE SubTask(
assignee INT References User(assignee),
subTaskID INT References Subtasks(subTaskID),
timeAllowed INT,
reportTo INT References Group(reportTo),
-- how do we reference SelectedTask?
);
```

If we use a surrogate key for the `SelectedTask` table, how do we use that in the `SubTask` table? If we use natural keys, the primary key could simply be a compound primary key of `userId` and `taskNumber`, and we could insert into both at the same time assuming we have programmatically gathered all of the pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper Postgres schema for your example could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE selected_task(
  selected_task_id serial PRIMARY KEY  -- surrogate PK
, user_id          int REFERENCES users(user_id)
, task_number      int
, name             text
, jobsite_id       int REFERENCES site(jobsite_id)
);

CREATE TABLE sub_task(
  sub_task_id      serial PRIMARY KEY
, selected_task_id int REFERENCES selected_task  -- this is how
, assignee         int REFERENCES users(assignee)
, time_allowed     int
, report_to        int REFERENCES groups(report_to)
);
```

- Use a [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column as surrogate PK.

  - [PostgreSQL SELECT primary key as "serial" or "bigserial"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90555/postgresql-select-primary-key-as-serial-or-bigserial/90567#90567)
  - [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)
  - [Use serial ID for multiple columns and return it from INSERT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76882/use-serial-id-for-multiple-columns-and-return-it-from-insert/76896#76896)
- You can't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `user` or `group` as identifier.
- Some other improvements. Detailed instructions here:

  - [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

#### `INSERT` in both tables at the same time?

Use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) with the `RETURNING` clause, or two `INSERT` statements in a transaction with [`lastval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html) (which is the Postgres equivalent for [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) @Aaron mentioned in his comment):

Related answer with code example for either method.

- [Inserting into related tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89451/inserting-into-related-tables/89458#89458)